# How to return null as zero in mysql?

Tags: mysql, join

i want to return pending as zero when it's null:

```
SELECT `t1`.*, `t2`.`pending` as IFNULL(ending, `0)`
FROM (`tblproducts` t1)
LEFT JOIN `cache_invoice` t2 ON `t1`.`id` = `t2`.`product_id`
LEFT JOIN `cache_stock` t3 ON `t1`.`id` = `t3`.`product_id`
```

error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(ending, `0)` FROM (`tblproducts` t1) LEFT JOIN `cache_invoice`
>   t2 ON `t1`.`id` ' at line 1

any idea where the problem is?

Comment: Not `IFNULL(ending, ``0)`` ` but `IFNULL(ending, 0)`.

Comment: @mparo_afridi, What is the column name on which you want to check IFNULL, do you also want to create alias name for it?

Comment: @mparo_afridi, Are pending and ending two separate columns?

Comment: no ending is alias of pending ,i am using only one column pending

Comment: So why confuse yourself and everybody else by introducing a poorly named alias?

Comment: thanks for suggestion next time i will take care, when using alias .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
`t2`.`pending` as IFNULL(ending, `0)`
```

You are checking IFNULL for an alias value of the column, while it should be as following:

```
IFNULL(`t2`.`pending`, 0) as ending
```

First evaluate if null - then show 0 and create alias if you want using 'AS' keyword. So, your query will be:

```
SELECT `t1`.*, IFNULL(`t2`.`pending`, 0) as ending
FROM `tblproducts` t1
LEFT JOIN `cache_invoice` t2 ON `t1`.`id` = `t2`.`product_id`
LEFT JOIN `cache_stock` t3 ON `t1`.`id` = `t3`.`product_id`
```

Comment: `$this->db->select("t1.*,IFNULL(t2.pending,0) as pending_bal,t3.available_qty as stock")
       ->from("tblproducts t1");`
looked here what's wrong here .
when i run and echo last_query this `IFNULL(t2.pending,0)` became this `IFNULL(t2.pending,\`0)\` '

Comment: This is PHP's code, right? This isn't relevant to your previous question at all...!!!

Comment: codeigniter active record code,i one up for you i going to accept your answer also ,but let me fix it first

Comment: I don't have any idea about codeigniter? Better to link your question to proper tag to improve the question.